# Division of a sum in polynomial rings.

Tags: polynomials, ring-theory

> Let $R$ be a UFD, and $p,q\in R[x]$, $a \in R$. I want to prove that if  $(x-a)\mid ((x-a)p+q)$ then it must divide $q$.

First of all, is this true? It seems pretty trivial but I cannot seem to prove it.

I am trying to use this to prove the derivative criterion for repeated factors, and if I have this then it all comes to place.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Since $x-a$ divides $(x-a)p+q$, there exists polynomial $L$ in $R[x]$ s.t. $L(x-a)=(x-a)p+q$.

Then $q =(L-p)(x-a)$.

Comment: Thanks... seemed pretty trivial. Maybe I am saturated, I feel pretty dumb now that I see it.

Comment: It's alright! Sometimes we tend to overthink too much especially when it comes to dense topics like abstract algebra. @BajoFondo